# Access Parent Class in List

Tags: java, list, inheritance, parent, super

I have following classes:

```
    public class MeasurementUnit(){ 
      ...
      private String name = "test";
      private List<MeasurementPoint> measPoints;
      ...
    }
```

and

```
public class MeasurementPoint(){ 
  ...
  private String name = "subtest";
  ...
}
```

I'm doing some `foreach` for creating tables or sometimes I have to give a certain `MeasurementPoint` from `measPoints` to a method... but is it somehow possible to access the name (or any other information) of the parent `MeasurementUnit` from a certain `MeasurementPoint`?

I think I could work with inheritance and `extend MeasurementPoint` with `MeasurementUnit`  but then I would store the information twice, wouldn't I (in `MeasurementUnit` and in the superclass of `MeasurementPoint`)?

Is there maybe a better solution or idea for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object `measPoints` is inside `MeasurementUnit` class if you iterate `measPoints` in class `MeasurementUnit` then you can access every member of class `MeasurementUnit` eg.

```
public class MeasurementUnit(){ 
      ...
          private String name = "test";
          private List<MeasurementPoint> measPoints;

          for(MeasurementPoint measPoint:measPoints){

         someOtherMethod(measPoint.getXXX(), measPoint.getYYYY(),name);

       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint but that doesn't work for me because I can't put the method (which requires a MeasurementPoint) into the MeasurementUnit Class. I have, lets say, a main class and a method which requires a measurementPoint as parameter(lets say this is not changeable). I make in instance of measurementUnit (with a List of MeasurementPoints) in the main class and do a foreach where i call the other method which requires a measurementPoint. In this method i do some calculating stuff but i would also like to use parameters from the parent measurementUnit (eg name).Maybe now it is more clear?

Comment: Hmm this looks like a designing issue. Do you have the permission to change the architecture of method call in your assignment ?

Comment: Yeah, it is some kind of designing issue. I'm using GWT and have to create  (among others) some CellTables.. I want to list all MeasurementPoints in one table (not MeasurementUnits) so I have to overgive a List with MeasurementPoints. But I would also like to display a column with the MeasurementUnit-Name .. or I want to create Popup with details for a special MeasurementPoint. I just overgive the popup-creating-method a MeasurementPoint.. but also there I would like to display parameters from the parent measurementUnit.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a getter for measPoints in MeasurementUnit, then add in MeasurementPoint's constructor a reference to your MeasurementUnit object and store it into an instance variable, and then reference this object every time you need to reference to measPoints.

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance solution sounds a bit weird to me.

I'd probably do something like:

```
public class MeasurementUnit(){ 
  ...
  private String name = "test";
  private List<MeasurementPoint> measPoints;
  ...
} 

public class MeasurementPoint(){ 
...
  private String name = "subtest";
  private MeasurementUnit parent;

  public MeasurementPoint(MeasurementUnit parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
...
}
```